# How to show the JSON spring boot logs as a seperate fields out of the messages in the table format

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a task that i need to view the spring boot JSON logs in the table format. It should not dump into the message field of kibana. It has to view as a seperate field in the table format.

Eg: EmployeeId 123
EmployeeName aathi
EmployeeAddress banglore.
I have used the Json processor to split the json log as a seperate variable to view it in a table format but i am not able to view the json logs in the table format.

Comment: It depends on your field_split attribute of kv filter. It will parse message and split it as table row. Ex; oldValue=aa,newValue=bb,modifiedField=cc message will be parsed and all fields will be row of table if you set kv filter as                   kv {
                      source => "message"
                      field_split => ", "
                  }

Answer (score 0):

You would need logstash to parse JSON in the fields/table format. In order to do it, ensure output of filebeat is redirected to Logstash. Pipeline should be Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elastic -> Kibana.

In logstash, JSON plugin filter will help to parse JSON. Please refer to logstash documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html
[JSON Filter Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html)

Once the JSON is parsed and stored in Elastic, you should see separate fields in Kibana which can be further used to build a different views (including tabular format)

Comment: Thank you kaushal i will try it and let you know.

Comment: how did it go? you're able to progress?